# Word Search using vectors in C++

Tags: c++, loops, matrix, vector

I would like assistance on how I can go about a project I was assigned in which a matrix of letters is printed and user-defined words are located in all directions on the grid and colored red using colormod.h and the matrix files he provides us with. For example, executing "a.exe hard project < 0505matrix" will print the assigned inputs of the matrix with the words "hard" and "project" in red text wherever located. I'm currently expanding on my previous project (shown below) in which one word was searched with specific coordinates to search given that returns "true" or "false" and I believe my first step would be to use nested for loops in some manner to allow the word to be searched WITHOUT the given coordinates. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

bool search(vector< vector<char> > &matr, char *word, int x, int y){

bool answer = false;
if(strlen(word)  > (matr.size()-y)){
    return false;   
}
else{
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        if(word[i] == matr[x][y + i])
    answer = true;
        else
    answer = false;
        break;
    }
}
return answer;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int x, y;
  string word;

  cin >> x;
  cin >> y;

  vector< vector<char> > matr;
  matr.resize(x);
  for(int i = 0; i < matr.size(); i++){
    matr[i].resize(y);
  }


   for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j<y ; j++){
    cin >> matr[i][j];
    }
    }
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
    cout <<  matr[i][j] << " ";
    }
      cout << endl;
    }

    cin >> word;

    cout << word;




  bool check = search(matr, argv[1], atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]));

  if(check){
      cout << "true" << endl;
  }
  else{
      cout << "false" << endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you work on an intermediate step: write a modified version of your function `search` that looks for a word starting at a given location *and extending in any direction.*

Comment: Every row and col can be treated as a string, and then find the input word(kmp algorithm).You can use two loops lonely with nested loop.